# Java threads problem

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, freeze

After last update (I can't find nothing criminal in it) my appication starts hang on after 1-2 hours of work. I profiled my app: everything was ok, but after some time I see this:

Hot spots:

[image]

Thread monitor:

[image]

What it can be? I have no idea, because Tomcat log doesn't contain errors and I can't see stack of operation (only `direct JVM call` - see at picture). Moreover, I have another application at this Tomcat, and it (another application) still perfectly works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you explicitly using the thread pool yourself?

Comment: Only one place where I create threads is notifications system. And I synchronized it in my last update. But, I think, I'll saw locks or stack in that code if I have problem inside that code. Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your HTTP connector thread pool, it's perfectly normal to have a number of waiting threads.

See this question for more details: [Apache Tomcat Request Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622715/apache-tomcat-request-threads/5622878#5622878).

Your table isn't very clear, but it looks like that consumed 88% of the execution of your app - they're not using 88% of the system's CPU time - after all, they're waiting threads.

Using stock settings, there are actually 25 waiting threads (see the linked question). 404 seconds / 25 over 2 hours doesn't seem excessive. That's around 8 seconds of CPU time per hour.

It's more likely that you just have a concurrency problem with your newly added synchronized functionality - you should probably post a question specific to that - it doesn't look like your issue is with Tomcat or it's thread pool if the other app continues to function.

---

Update

> **Difference between BLOCKED state and WAITING / TIMED_WAITING
>   states?**
>
> When a thread calls Object.wait method, it releases all the acquired
>   monitors and is put into WAITING (or TIMED_WAITING if we call the
>   timeout versions of the wait method) state. Now when the thread is
>   notified either by notify() or by notifyAll() call on the same object
>   then the waiting state of the thread ends and the thread starts
>   attempting to regain all the monitors which it had acquired at the
>   time of wait call. At one time there may be several threads trying to
>   regain (or maybe gain for the first time) their monitors. If more than
>   one threads attempt to acquire the monitor of a particular object then
>   only one thread (selected by the JVM scheduler) is granted the monitor
>   and all other threads are put into BLOCKED state. Got the difference?

Source: http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/07/threadstate-in-java-blocked-vs-waiting.html

Comment: Not necessarily. Depending on how you've coded you app, it's easy to just have threads in a waiting state.

Comment: Use a tool like JConsole to look at the waiting threads to give you an idea of what they're waiting on.

Comment: You can use whatever you want, I said a tool _like_ JConsole. If you're happy analysing thread stacks with JProfiler (if it has that functionality), go for it. :D

Comment: The problem was in resource bundles (config file with translations). Visually i can't find any errors inside it and can't find it by profiler. But I found bug by adding one commit after another.

My question was awful, your answer cant help me, but thanks for spending your time.

Comment: Glad you got the issue sorted. :)